# Micronaut alternative for spring-integration

Tags: sftp, micronaut

I'm migrating a spring boot app to micronaut framework and I'm nearly done with it, the only missing piece is a micronaut alternative to spring-integration.
Basically I need to periodically scan a remote sftp server for files and then do some work on them.
In my spring boot app I'd just use spring-integration but I'd like to achieve this the micronaut way but I'm yet to find one.

Is there a micronaut specific way to handle files on sftp servers similar to spring-integration?
I'd like to avoid doing it "manually" via scheduled jobs if possbile.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no library specific to Micronaut for this purpose that I'm aware of